# Troubles using strtr for converting special chars

Tags: php

```
$string = strtr($string,
"ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûýýþÿŔŕ", 
"aaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuuybsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuyybyRr");
```

So I have the following line of code to convert the special characters to normal characters. However, it is not returning me the characters as it should.

For example:

```
Thïs is á tëst
```

returns:

```
thrs-is-r-trst
```

It seems like every special char is just returned as the last letter in the list.

The complete code snippet:

```
$string = strtr($_POST['title'], 
"ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûýýþÿŔŕ", 
"aaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuuybsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuyybyRr");

$string = trim($string);

$string = str_replace (" ", "-", $string);

$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/', '', $string);

$string = strtolower($string);
```

Comment: strtr() isn't documented as being binary safe (meaning that it actually works on bytes rather than on characters); why not use mb_convert_encoding() or iconv() instead?

Comment: Always interesting that people refer to "special characters". What is special about certain characters, how do they differ from "non special" characters?

Comment: @arkascha Argh!! One of my pet peeves indeed. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [TFM](http://php.net/strtr):

> If given three arguments, this function returns a copy of `str` where all occurrences of each ***(single-byte) character*** in `from` have been translated to the corresponding character in `to`, i.e., every occurrence of `$from[$n]` has been replaced with `$to[$n]`, where `$n` is a valid offset in both arguments.

`strtr` treats your input strings as single byte characters. But you almost certainly have them in encoded as multibyte characters, so they're not being parsed correctly. You should use `strtr`'s second form:

> If given two arguments, the second should be an array in the form `array('from' => 'to', ...)`. The return value is a string where all the occurrences of the array keys have been replaced by the corresponding values. The longest keys will be tried first. Once a substring has been replaced, its new value will not be searched again.

```
$string = strtr($_POST['title'], array('À' => 'a', 'Á' => 'a', ...));
```

This should treat multibyte strings correctly.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php#90925](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php#90925) gives a complete array of characters.

Comment: It works, but isn't there a better way to accomplish this? Using `mb_convert_encoding()` or similar?

Comment: @Amal Perhaps `iconv` with `//TRANSLIT` or the into `Transliterator` class, yes. That really depends on the OP's goal and how well the mapping he's looking for is already established in the above two libraries. An encoding conversion is not really what's looking for though.